Mongodb has 500 million documents and i want to search with regEx based on two fields in javascript driver not schema
My MongoDb has around 500 million documents looking like the following:
{
  "_id": objectId,
  "Name": "John Smith",
  "Address": "132, My Street, Kingston, New York 12401"
}

Now i want to query the data based on the Name Regex and Address Regex as sometimes the name is case sensitive in my database and sometimes address too. I have tried creating separate index (1) for both fields, also tried creating compound index with text (in text index the problem is it only searches if the text index was on one field either Address or Name doesn't work with both field's index with text).
Also tried both fields index as: createIndex({Name: 1, Address: 1}); <--- this returns data also if i search with one field only. I want to perform a query like:
var name = "john smith";
var address = "new york";

 var userData = await db
      .collection("userData")
      .find({
        $and: [
          { Name: { $regex: new RegExp(name, "i") } },
          { Address: { $regex: new RegExp(address, "i") } },
        ],
      })
      .skip(skip)
      .limit(limitNumber)
      .toArray();

If i try with single index i can still perform query with one field not with both fields. I tried both fields with all above methods it takes forever to load even i tried extending the query ms time still doesn't return anything or even an error.

Thanks

Wrt indexes for case-insensitive regex search: "Case-insensitive indexes typically do not improve performance for  $regex queries. The  $regex  implementation is not collation-aware and cannot utilize case-insensitive indexes efficiently."

Try this one:
var userData = await db
  .collection("userData")
  .find({
      Name: { $regex: name, $options: "i" },
      Address: { $regex: address, $options: "i" } 
  })

$and operator is not needed.
If you like to use it, then you must use it with $expr
var userData = await db
  .collection("userData")
  .find({ $expr: {
    $and: [
      { $regexMatch: { input: "$Name", regex: name, options: "i" } },
      { $regexMatch: { input: "$Address", regex: address, options: "i" } }
    ],
  }})


So what index is needed for it? {Name: 1, Address: 1}?
Thanks

@JahanzaibKhan: indexes won't help with queries of this nature. (kinda. A full index scan is probably still better than full collection scan, but it'll still be much slower than equality or range query)

It does not use an index. This answer only makes your query working.

var userData = await db
  .collection("userData")
  .find({
      Name: { $regex: name, $options: "i" },
      Address: { $regex: address, $options: "i" } 
  })

Already tried this, it didn't help.
and tried the second one too still nothing received.

@WernfriedDomscheit it is not returning anything. it only returns when i search regEx on one field no matter what index i do or not!.

i just tried :
.find({
$or: [
{ Name: { $regex: new RegExp(name, "i") } },
{ Address: { $regex: new RegExp(address, "i") } },
],
})
it returned few matching name and address but also returned others matching with name or address.

so i have test more and more and found out if i dont the have compound index for both Name and Address field together the query takes 500 seconds otherwise it takes 85 seconds if i query with regex on both fields.
Thanks everyone.

compound index with asc order not text needed.
